# Scroll if element not in windows view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have a table where you can select an element and then when ever you press the up or down arrow key the next or previous table row will be selected.

for this purpose i have created the following jquery:

```
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var ar=new Array(33,34,35,36,37,39);
    if(selected_row_id != null){
        var key = e.which;
        // up
        if(key == 38){
            $('#'+selected_row_id).prev().trigger('click');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        //down
        if(key == 40 ){
            $('#'+selected_row_id).next().trigger('click');
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if($.inArray(key,ar) > -1) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

This works fine however it has one mistake that annoys me. When a table row is further down than you can actually see on the screen (meaning that you would have to scroll) the window doesnt scroll automaticly.

My question is how is it possible to make sure that the window scrolls when an element is not visible on the screen?

Comment: Try checking if the element's top offset is within the window's height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function taken from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling):

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom)
      && (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) &&  (elemTop >= docViewTop) );
}
```

Returns `true` if the element is completely visible in the window, `false` otherwise.

If `false` is returned, then you can scroll your window appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

Look at ScrollTo: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp

Comment: But how can i check with javascript if the element is outside of the window frame?

Comment: you can do that by calculating view port offset. Solution in answer below shows you how.